# Why do the bride and groom go round the fire 7 times during the marriage rituals?

Tags: rituals, marriage

I read a post which said the reason to be that from numbers 1-9 only number by which 360 cannot be divided is 7 so they go 7 rounds which symbolises that their bond is un breakable, but I read something related to saptapadi.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.